# Does each SelectionKey (or SelectionKeyImpl) have a unique identifier (id) that I can use?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nio, nonblocking

I need to have a unique ID for each of my `SelectionKey`. Can I use some internal id from the `SelectionKeyImpl`? I could use the FD for example, but I am not confident I will be always unique per `SelectionKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your own ids (such as java.util.UUID) and attach them to the keys via SelectionKey.attach(Object) or when registering the channel with the Selector

Answer (score 1):

There is no FD in a SelectionKey. There is an FD you can reach via the underlying Channel but a channel may have several SelectionKeys so that's no use to you. All you have is the SelectionKey's own identity.